# ngrx StoreModule.forRoot Naming convention

Tags: angular, ngrx, store

So inside my Angular Application in app.module.ts I have the following:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  applicationState: applicationReducer,
}),
```

and in my app.reducer.ts File there is this:

```
export const initialState: AppState = {
  page: {
    items: [],
    data: {
      prop1: 0,
      prop2: 0,
      ...
    }
  },
  more: ""
}

export const moviesReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(...),
  on(...)
);
```

Now I cannot acces the data in my AppState correctly if I do it like above.
Only If I change the forRoot() like so:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({
  page: applicationReducer,
}),
```

it works.

can a State only have one single element in it, or do i have to have different reducers for different properties, or what am I missing here?

In the reducer, I would want to access the whole state with "page", and all its subbarts, aswell as "more"... as one Object.

How can I do this? I dont understand why the the naming in forRoot must be the same as the property inside the appState, and if it has to be, how can I access the whole state, and how do we handle nested Objects?

I think I am missing something quite easy here...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, within the root state (AppState in your case), you'll have a reducer for each property within that state. Example:

```js
// Your root / main app state
export interface AppState {
  page: PageState,
  more: SomeOtherState
}

// State for a page.
export interface PageState {
  items: any[],
  // ...
}

// and so on...
export interface SomeOtherState {
  // ... other state properties
}

export const initialPageState: PageState = {
 items: [],
 // ... other initial values
};

export const initialOtherState: SomeOtherState {
  // ... initial key value pairs
}

export const initialAppState: AppState = {
  page: initialPageState,
  more: initialOtherState
};

// Reducer for page state
export const pageReducer = createReducer(
  initialPageState,

  on(...),
  on(...)
);

export const otherReducer = createReducer(
  initialOtherState,
  
  on(...),
  on(...)
);
```

Then when you include it into your app module, it would look like:

```js
StoreModule.forRoot({
  page: pageReducer,
  more: otherReducer
}),
```

In feature stores, the paradigm shifts slightly. There, you'll have a reducer for the entire feature state... and not for each property within the feature state.